# How to make object point and shoot another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[asd.peeneje](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvxhZ.png)

Hello friends! I'm developing a game 2d platformer in #Unity, I need to make this object on the right side look at the other object on the left side and shoot in his direction. I don't know to do this. Can you help me in this? :D

I'm maked multiple attempts and I haven't made it. I try with this

```
        if(isPointer) {

            targetRotation = pointer.transform.position - transform.position;

            angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetRotation.y, targetRotation.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                
            gun.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0, angle));

            break;

                    }
void Shoot () {

    if(shootTimer <= 0f) {

        var Ball = Instantiate(ball, gun.position, transform.rotation, transform.parent);
    
        var forward = transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;
    
        targetRotation.z = 0;

        if(isPointer) {

                finalTarget = (forward.z * -transform.position).normalized;

                break;

        }

        Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(finalTarget * speedBall, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().ShootAni();

        switch(weaponLoot1) {

            case WeaponLoot1.glack:

                shootTimer = 0.2f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.silenced:

                shootTimer = 0.2f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.revolver:

                shootTimer = 0.5f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.shotgun:

                shootTimer = 0.55f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.mac10:

                shootTimer = 0.15f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.tommy:

                shootTimer = 0.2f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.ak47:

                shootTimer = 0.2f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.m4a1:

                shootTimer = 0.2f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.rifle:

                shootTimer = 0.6f;

                break;

            case WeaponLoot1.bazooka:

                shootTimer = 0.75f;

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

So you'll have

```
gun.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(pointer.transform.position - transform.position);
```